# tex4ebook: Issues with sections in ebooks

Tags: sectioning, make4ht, tex4ebook, epub

In an old version of tex4ebook (beginning of 2022), sections worked fine. With the current version, however, I run into issues and cannot compile the file anymore. I use the arguments `-a debug -c config.cfg -f epub3 "%wm"`

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\section{Header of Section 1} 

Text within section 1.

\section{Header of Section 2}

Text within section 2.

\end{document}
```

And a simple config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

If I instead use the config file proposed [here](https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook/blob/master/README.md), I receive the error message "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size = 10000]".

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\CutAt{section}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

If I use the following config file with the no-cut option, I receive the same error as if I use the very first config file (the one without the CutAt command):

```
\Preamble{xhtml,no-cut}
\CutAt{section}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Comment: Try the 'no-cut' option. It is necessary to be used when you use custom Cut command

Comment: @michal.h21 I now tried the no-cut option, but I receive the same error and still cannot compile the file. Did I something wrong in the config file?

Comment: @michal.h21 I just found out that the issue seems to result from the documentclass - if I use "book" I run into issues, if I use "article" it works. Is there a way to get it work also for documentclass "book"?

Comment: I am not sure, I just got to a computer, and the configuration file with `no-cut` option seems to work with your file, even with the book class, without `\chapter` commands. Maybe try the `\CutAt{section,chapter}`, but I am not sure if it changes anything.

Comment: @michal.h21 Unfortunately, it did not change anything. I always get the error message ```! Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again> \\endcsname l.6 \section{Header of Section 1}```.

Comment: I get the same error message when I use ```\chapter``` instead of ```\section```. Only ```\part```, ```\subsection``` and ```\paragraph``` are working.

Comment: It looks like the problem is the ```-a debug``` argument, that I forward to the compiler. If I remove that argument, the file get compiled, both for chapters and sections.

Comment: maybe you have an older local installation of `tex4ebook`? What does `tex4ebook -v` say?

Comment: @michal.h21 ```tex4ebook -v``` provides "tex4ebook> tex4ebook v0.3j". MiKTeX shows me a date of my ```tex4ebook``` version as of "19.03.2023". Do I have to update that?

Comment: no, that's an actual version. It is strange why should this option cause issues. Anyway, you don't need to use this option unless you need to debug something, so you can stop it for now.